# How does the syntax of the OR comparison operator || work in JS?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have a code snippet below which i'm trying to find if a field has a value of 90 or not. I've tried it with only the one field and it works fine but when I add the other two in with ORs all of them don't work:

The working script:

```
if (number1 === "90") {
    message = "Right angle";
}
```

The not working script:

```
if (number1 || number2 || number3 === "90") {
    message = "Right angle";
}
```

On the bottom code snippet the term "right angle" is returned for any value

Comment: if `number1` is actual a number ,then don't compare to a string

Comment: You can't short-circuit comparisons like that. Your expression is evaluated as `(number1) || (number2) || (number3 === "90")`

Comment: Pro-tip `number1 == 90` will also account for it being the string representation

Comment: To follow on the above comment: so it should be `if (number1==="90" || number2==="90" || number3==="90")`

Comment: `if( [number1, number2, number3].includes("90") ) { .. }`

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan that's not a pro-tip, it's a noob one.  A pro would ensure that the variable is explicitly coerced into the expected type _before_ comparison.  It's the only way to eliminate the WAT?! factor.

Comment: @Alnitak, I know that, you know that. I just didn't know how to phrase it without being insulting; so I pretended it was a pro-tip

Comment: Though unrelated, I'd say:  noob: use `==`, junior pro: use `===`, seasoned pro: I use `==` because I know what I'm doing, pro-pro: use `===` cause someone else might see your code that doesn't know what they're doing!